# Google places API error: 'google' is not defined with Edge & Firefox

Tags: jquery, api, firefox, google-api, microsoft-edge

So have two input and when you starting typing an address it will give you a list of results. It works on chrome but for some reason, I can't figure out why it gives this error in Edge:

[image]

> Edge version: Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0
>
> Firefox version: Version 65.0 (64-bit)

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w9tsr8kf/1/)

```html
  <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS"
        crossorigin="anonymous" />

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <form id="distance_form">
        <div class="form-group"><label>Origin: </label> <input class="form-control" id="from_places" placeholder="Enter a location" />
          <input id="origin" name="origin" required="" type="hidden" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group"><label>Destination: </label> <input class="form-control" id="to_places" placeholder="Enter a location" />
          <input id="destination" name="destination" required="" type="hidden" />
        </div>

      </form>
      <script>
      $(function () {
          // add input listeners
          google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function () {
            var from_places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
              document.getElementById("from_places")
            );
            var to_places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
              document.getElementById("to_places")
            );
          });
        });
      </script>
      


      <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCteSKX5TJVTK5GAdDktqmE2ebuDSPTU-4&libraries=places&language=en"></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: You are asynchronously loading the Google Maps Javascript API v3 script (with `async defer`).  Either load it synchronously (remove those, and move it above the code that depends on it), or use the asynchronous callback (as recommended by Google (and the answer below).

Answer (score 1):

Try to modify your code as below:

When the Google Maps API is ready, it will call the function specified (initMap function) using the callback parameter.

```
<script>
    function initMap() {
        // add input listeners
        var from_places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            document.getElementById("from_places")
        );
        var to_places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            document.getElementById("to_places")
        );
    }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCteSKX5TJVTK5GAdDktqmE2ebuDSPTU-4&libraries=places&language=en&callback=initMap"></script>
```

The output as below (using Edge browser 42.17134.1.0 version):

[image]

More detail about using Google Maps API, you could check [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) and [Google Maps API Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete).